# Sinatra Application models/routes to dynamically load per user

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra, models, helper

We currently have an application running Sinatra that different users from different areas visit. When a user logs in it figures out which area you are in, and shows you the routes, helpers and models to load.

Currently when users are browsing, the application seems to be remembering the location of the previous user that clicked (or logged in) and switches the whole application to that configuration and location.

I have tried to change the application to load instead of require the files needed (as I have been told that this will reload the files each time) and we thought it was solved, but it seems to have come up again.

Is the answer to this problem to have the applications running separately, or is there another way around this?

Comment: Can you tell us _how_ you hold the information about the user location?

Comment: Are you using class level variables to store state?  If so, that's likely the cause of your issue.

Comment: @uri-agassi Hi, the user location is stored in a session variable.

Comment: @mcfinnigan We're using instance variables to store the path of the file that needs to be loaded

Comment: How do you manage your sessions?

Comment: @UriAgassi this is managed through the Sinatra core. We reference the session using  
  
    if session[:path]
        load ".#{session[:path]}/dashboard.rb"
    end

The dashboard.rb file is where the routes are loaded for that relevant path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to an answer on this, it seems that loading the files still leaves a memory, I've put the models into namespaces which has fixed the issue. Putting the models into a namespace and referencing with the namespace.